# Making legend appear using arcpy.mp?

Tags: arcpy, legend, arcgis-pro

New to programming here. My legend (bottom left corner) keeps showing up blank even though there is technically a legend element there. Am I missing something in my code? I've included the relevant code and an image of my map.

```
lyrFile = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(meaninc)
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("E:/2016Fall/ProgrammingFundamentals/Final/Maps/Maps.aprx")
# Ask user to input their desired file name and location
location = input("Input file path:")
map = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
# Remove previous layer files
for l in map.listLayers():
  if l.name in names:
    map.removeLayer(l)
# Add desired layer file
map.addLayer(lyrFile)
# Turn on the legend???
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout")[0]
legend = lyt.listElements("LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
legend.visible = True
# Export PDF layout
lyt.exportToPDF(location)

aprx.save()
del aprx
```

[image]

Comment: It might be the drawing order of your elements, i.e., your data frame or some other masking element may block it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've changed the underlying basemap to a simple topo and put the legend at the top of the drawing order. Now it shows up, but it's not updating when I change my input layer file in the line: lyrFile = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(meaninc)

Comment: It sounds like you have solved your original problem, but have a new one, so now, while there are no answers is the time to heavily revise it to reflect where you are *now* stuck.